# SpringBatch, chunk processing and trying to revert non-transactionnal changes on a chunk rollback

Tags: spring-batch

I have a chunk processing step that:

- 1) Creates an user in database
- 2) Opens an account on a remote system, through an HTTP call

We pay for the accounts on the remote system, and during batch failures, we would like to avoid creating remote accounts that will never be used because the users has been rollbacked in our database...

If I have a chunk size of 100, then if an exception occurs during the remote call of 2) for the 50th item, then my business logic can catch that exception, try to close the remote account of that specific item, and then rethrow the exception to trigger the chunk rollback.

But then, for the 49th items processed before, the users in database will be rollbacked, but the accounts won't be closed.

So, 50 users will be rollbacked on the DB, but only 1 remote account will be closed.

How can I organise my step to be able to close the 50 remote accounts (if this manual rollback fails, it is not a consistency issue: best effort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an extra step to close unwanted account? Every opened account is stored in extra table (`OPENED_ACCOUNT`) in its own transaction, so it will not be rolled back by spring-batch.
Clean up step will operate along data stored in `OPENED_ACCOUNT` and you can have restart on error, manage custom retry operation etc.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to underderstand what you mean. I don't understand when you insert something in the `OPENED_ACCOUNT` table

Comment: Every time you create a valid account you store this information in `OPENED_ACCOUNT` table (using separate transaction); when you save chunk you will delete `OPENED_ACCOUNT` content in the same transaction: if chunk commit fails you have in `OPENED_ACCOUNT` the accounts to delete in cleanup step

Comment: But the insertion into the OPENED_ACCOUNT could also fail. Btw wouldn't it be easier to store the current chunk opened accounts inside the step ExecutionContext?